# Automatically close outdated GitLab merge request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Is there any option to automatically close GitLab merge request after 1 day?
Manually close all the merge requests is not an option since there are many each day.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom script that uses GitLab API either [directly](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html) or [via client](https://about.gitlab.com/partners/#api-clients)

You'll need to generate [private token](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) with Scope: api

**Example**

1. [Fetch Merge Requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests) updated before a specific date:

```
$ PRIVATE_TOKEN=****
$ curl -s -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
    "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/merge_requests?state=opened&view=simple&updated_before=2020-02-01T14:09:18.679Z" |\
     jq '.[].id'
34520388
33038903
20988416
```

(put your token instead of ****)

2. Call [Update request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr) for each id in a loop, specifying `state_event=close`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ivan, I will definitely try it out!